# Displaying Connected Posts in a Grid using PHP Loop

Tags: php, css

I've been searching through the forums and Google for a few days on how to resolve this and have yet to find a solution. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Bottom line, I am looking to achieve this:

Speaker Section

[image]

Using Firebug to inspect the element, I've determined which classes apply:

```html
<div class="et_pb_section  et_pb_section_8 et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">



  <div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_6">


    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_10">

      <div class="et_pb_blog_grid_wrapper">
        <div class="et_pb_blog_grid clearfix et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_  et_pb_cpt_loop_archive_0 et_pb_cpt_archive_grid" data-columns="">
          <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_cpt et_pb_row_4col">
            <div class="et_cpt_container_column et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_0">
              <div class="et_pb_section  et_pb_section_10 et_section_regular">



                <div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_7">


                  <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_11">

                    <div class="et_pb_module et-waypoint et_pb_image et_pb_animation_off desaturate et_pb_cpt_featured_image2_0 et_always_center_on_mobile et-animated">
                      <a href="http://meetingoftheminds.org/speaker/scot-rourke"><img src="http://meetingoftheminds.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Scot-Rourke.jpg" alt="">
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_cpt_title_0">
                      <h2 itemprop="name" class="cpt_title page_title entry-title"><a href="http://meetingoftheminds.org/speaker/scot-rourke">Scot Rourke</a></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix et_pb_module  et_pb_acf_single_item_0">
                      <div class="sb_mod_acf_single_item clearfix">
                        <p>‎Chief Information and Transformation Officer, Technology, Innovation &amp; Performance</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix et_pb_module  et_pb_acf_single_item_1">
                      <div class="sb_mod_acf_single_item clearfix">
                        <p>Cuyahoga County</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- .et_pb_column -->
                </div>
                <!-- .et_pb_row -->

              </div>
              <!-- .et_pb_section -->
            </div>
```

I then tried to tailor this to my PHP Loop but the result is radically different than expected.

Here is the snippet of the original loop:

```
<?php

// Get the connected posts
$my_connected_posts = Post_Connector::API()->get_children( "sessions-to-speakers", get_the_id() );
// Check
if ( count( $my_connected_posts ) > 0 ) {
    // Loop
    foreach ( $my_connected_posts as $my_connected_post ) {

        // Display the featured image, title with link, job, and company
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $my_connected_post, 'thumbnail') . "<br/>";
        echo "<a href='" . get_permalink( $my_connected_post->ID ) . "'>" . $my_connected_post->post_title . "</a>" . "<br/>";
        echo get_field("job", $my_connected_post) . "<br/>";
        echo get_field("company", $my_connected_post) . "<br/>"; 

        }

                    }

?>
```

Original loop displays posts vertically down the page as shown here:

Connected Posts

[image]

Here is the snippet of the modified loop, using the "Speaker Section" classes, which only seems to resize the thumbnails:

```
<!-- Speaker Section -->
<div class="et_pb_section  et_pb_section_8 et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">
  <div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_6">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_10">
      <div class="et_pb_blog_grid_wrapper">
        <div class="et_pb_blog_grid clearfix et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_  et_pb_cpt_loop_archive_0 et_pb_cpt_archive_grid" data-columns="">
          <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_cpt et_pb_row_4col">

            <?php

// Get the connected posts
$my_connected_posts = Post_Connector::API()->get_children( "sessions-to-speakers", get_the_id() );
// Check
if ( count( $my_connected_posts ) > 0 ) {
    // Loop
    foreach ( $my_connected_posts as $my_connected_post ) {

// #speaker section
echo '<div class="et_cpt_container_column et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_0"><div class="et_pb_section  et_pb_section_10 et_section_regular">';
    echo '<div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_7">';
        echo '<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_11">';

        // Display the featured image, title with link, job, and company
echo '<div class="et_pb_module et-waypoint et_pb_image et_pb_animation_off desaturate et_pb_cpt_featured_image2_0 et_always_center_on_mobile et-animated">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $my_connected_post, 'thumbnail') . "<br/>";
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="clearfix et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_left  et_pb_cpt_title_0">';
        echo "<a href='" . get_permalink( $my_connected_post->ID ) . "'>" . $my_connected_post->post_title . "</a>" . "<br/>";
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="clearfix et_pb_module  et_pb_acf_single_item_0">';
echo '<div class="sb_mod_acf_single_item clearfix">';
        echo get_field("job", $my_connected_post) . "<br/>";
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="clearfix et_pb_module  et_pb_acf_single_item_1">';
echo '<div class="sb_mod_acf_single_item clearfix">';
        echo get_field("company", $my_connected_post) . "<br/>"; 
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>'; 
echo '</div>'; 
        }

                    }

?>
```

Comment: Those CSS classes come from wordpress divi page builder. Unless you want to use the exact CSS styles from the page you got that from, you will have to include the CSS stylesheet(s) that page is using. Or you can build this using another styling framework such as Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Why does your foreach loop in PHP have the same variable for the key as the array you are looping through?

Comment: Yolo,
I didn't add it to the snippet but there is a call to the header earlier in the file, so that's where I plug into the stylesheet. I have done some light reading on Bootstrap and may choose to go that route if I can't find a solution by the end of the week.

Kobbe,
I've tried changing it but it throws a white screen of death. Perhaps it has something to with the API? I found a similar instance [here](https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/many-to-many-post-relationship/) where the only difference is plural vs. singular among the variables in the loop.